# Scala sbt order of imports

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

Is it possible to change the order of imports in sbt for scala compilation?

I have two unmanaged dependencies in the ./lib/ folder and the rest are managed dependencies in the sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.10",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.10",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-log4j12" % "1.7.10",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.2",
  "edu.washington.cs.knowitall.taggers" %% "taggers-core" % "0.4",
  "com.rockymadden.stringmetric" % "stringmetric-core" % "0.25.3",
  "org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "4.3.1",
  "com.twitter" %% "util-collection" % "6.3.6",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.10",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2"
)
```

In Eclipse I can run my program, because I can change the order of imports in the java build path (I put unmanaged dependencies at the end).
However when I want to run it from the terminal:

```
sbt "run-main de.questionParser.Test"
```

I get the following error

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Lists.reverse(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
```

So the final question is:
Is it possible to change the order of imports  in sbt for scala compilation so that managed dependencies are included before unmanaged dependencies?

Comment: Can you post what's your custom lib in ./lib folder?

Comment: I have self-packaged: "babelnet-api-2.5.1.jar" and "oqa_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: @Anonim33 could you please tell how you resolved this issue? I am also facing the same issue.